Why Does our Water Heater Push Hot Water Through the Cold Water Pipes/Lines When Water is Turned Completely Off to the House?
I am new here and hope I'm in the right place. I have many skills and talents, one of them being basic plumbing repair and upgrade jobs. I live in a manufactured home and the supply lines to things were not done well nor did anything have shutoff valves, just plastic tubes with 1/2" FIP nuts from the 1/2" pipes straight to whatever was being supplied with water. Our dishwasher was even connected to cold water! So, as of the beginning of this year I removed the old supply lines to lots of things and added shutoff valves to the pipes paired with braided stainless steel supply lines to replace the plastic ones as well as re-routing the dishwasher to connect to the hot water pipe with an add-a-tee adapter.
Now, with said context, someone I live with in the house had their plastic supply line to their toilet burst and almost flood the bathroom. So, I turned water off to the trailer to stop that so I could proceed to clean up the water and remove the old supply line down to just the pipe coming out of the floor and I heard the water heater start to make a bubbling sound as it is right there near that bathroom behind a wall, and hot water started flowing at a quite fast rate from that cold water toilet pipe! I reiterate, the water is turned completely of the the trailer. So while that pipe is actively trying to re-flood the bathroom I had to act quick to wrap the threads in PTFE tape, add a 1/2" FIP x 3/8" COMP. straight shutoff valve, and attach a 3/8" COMP. x 7/8 Toilet connector to the valve and then the toilet.
I got it done and no leaks have emerged whatsoever, however, more plumbing projects I can handle need to be done. I plan to remove the supply lines to our bathroom sinks which is plumbed really strange, but add 4 shutoff valves for each 1/2" threaded output on the houses pipes, add PEX-A tubing and coupling nuts to new faucets as PEX-A is flexible and could bend a little the way I need it. Now, with all of this long story said, I have googled and looked everywhere as to why hot water starts doing that and it's called water heater siphoning, but I cannot figure out how to stop it in my specific situations. It only happens when fittings are removed from pipes and hot water starts coming out of them enough to make a major mess. I've been told that opening hot on a nearby fixture will stop this, but that doesn't work.
So, before I work on this next project someday, how do I stop this from happening?
I've attached an image also of the pipes I'll be working with in the next project so you can see what I work with just in case and the old lines that are still there, functioning, but need to be replaced as they are not safe without shutoff valves, and they are years old and have been there for the 13 years we've lived here. Thanks if anyone can help direct me into stopping the siphoning

Heating of water increases water pressure a bit.  That increase can push hot water into the cold water line a bit, especially if the cold water pressure is reduced.

Does the water supply to the mobile home have a check valve, aka a backflow prevent valve, between the mobile home and the water main?

Is the water heater an electric tank? relatively low height?

Because you didn't turn off the water heater when you turned off the water. The lower water pressure lowered the boiling point inside the water heater, and that made it easier for water to boil at the heating element.  And that increased pressure.

You have no cutoff valve to the inlet to the water heater, and the toilet line failed and began spraying. You turned off the shutoff for all water to the house and this would have stopped water under pressure from spraying, but there would be two routes water could siphon out of the heater--the hot water out line and the cold water inlet. The latter would be what caused the continuing flow from the cold suppy to the toilet, and this would drain the tank almost entirely. In your case the best thing would have been to keep all the hot taps closed to try to lower the pressure at the top.

While water logically flows:

Water main -->
Hot water heater -->
Hot water pipes -->
Faucets, etc.

if there are no valves to shut things off and no backflow prevention then all the water is connected and flows wherever it wants to go, which generally means to the lowest point.
Take an extreme example: Hot water tank is on the roof. In that case, water under pressure goes up and into the hot water tank (because without pressure it can't go "up") and water under pressure (because of the continuous pressure from the water in the water main) comes out. What happens if you turn off the cold water going into the tank? Gravity will still let the water flow down to all of the faucets and other hot water fixtures.
The same thing will happen, to a lesser degree, if the hot water tank is inside the house. The difference is that the gravity-driven pressure will be lower. But it still exists. The only exception is if the tank is in the lower level of a two-story building. Then you will not normally get much out of the faucets on the second floor if the water main is turned off.
In addition, their can be actual siphoning in certain situations where even though the output from the tank is on the top of the tank and you might think that no water can flow because there is nothing (with the water main shut off) to push the water up. But as long as there is still water in the pipes from the water heater to the faucet, there can be a siphoning effect that will move the water, and more water than just what remains in the pipes - you can literally empty an entire water tank this way.
So how do you avoid this problem if you don't have shutoff valves on the input (cold) and output (hot) pipes going into the tank? Simple:

Shut off the water main
Ideally, turn off the water heater. Why? In case the siphoning effect actually results in it partially emptying, that can cause problems for the heating elements.
Open at least one hot water faucet. Actually, I would open at least one hot and one cold because there can be water in lots of pipes/fixtures.
Once the water stops running you can work on the pipes.

There are some possible complications. If the faucet you open - or the pipe you are going to work on - is well below the top of the tank then you could end up emptying the tank! Which is why one useful project once you are doing plumbing work, is to add cold and hot water shutoff valves very close to the hot water heater.

DV care to explain or to write a better answer?

Current codes actually require a siphon-breaker valve or other means of breaking a siphon. Which does not mean the OP's water heater has one (evidently it does not, indeed.) IPC 504.1 and 504.2 for example.
